# Eclipse weblogic domain creation failed. Input line too long

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I have a weird problem, and can't really understand what is going on.

Everything was working fine before the system admins updated the Java version on my pc.

I am using Eclipse neon OEPE 12.2.1.4 With WebLogic 12.1.2.

After the update I couldn't launch the WebLogic server, it says:

> Console message: 
>   
> The input line is too long. 
>   :process_path cannot be used now. 
>   
>   Error message:
>   Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. Connection refused: connect.

Something happened with the domain path maybe, but can't figure out where can I find it.

I tried to drop the server, and create a new one. It is possible to create a new one, with the same domain (not working), but when I try to create a new domain I have the following error message:

> Domain creation failed. Please check WebLogic Server Command Line Console for detailed error message.
>   
>   The console:
>   Executing WLST script...
>   Input line is too long.
>   :process_path cannot be used now.

I think it must be a very trivial solution, and something went wrong around the domain, but I can't figure out where should I shorten the path.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after wasted two days for the solution, finally found the answer. I examined three sides of the problem.

- The integrated WebLogic server
- The Eclipse configurations
- The JRE/JDK

**WebLogic server:**
First of all I tried to *clean* on the server, but didn't work. Deleted it, and created a new one. the Eclipse allowed to create a new server, but didn't allow to create a new domain. After opened the [error logs](https://manuelselva.wordpress.com/2008/01/25/where-is-eclipse-error-log/), it became clear that the problem caused by the WLST script.

**Eclipse:**
Didn't find anything wrong with the Eclipse settings, so I reinstalled it. After the fresh installation the problem still existed, i got the same error message like before.

**JRE/JDK:**
Deleted and reinstalled everything and it didn't start to work simply, it needed a final *clean*, and now everything is working fine again.